# Python - Plot candlesticks from a list

Tags: python

Newbie here! I have a list. The list contains 200 of these structures. That list contains financial values I would like to plot as candlesticks. Just "Open", "close", "High", "Low" and "Close Time" are the ones I want to plot, as usual.

```
 [
    [
        1499040000000,      # Open time
        "0.01634790",       # Open
        "0.80000000",       # High
        "0.01575800",       # Low
        "0.01577100",       # Close
        "148976.11427815",  # Volume
        1499644799999,      # Close time
        "2434.19055334",    # Quote asset volume
        308,                # Number of trades
        "1756.87402397",    # Taker buy base asset volume
        "28.46694368",      # Taker buy quote asset volume
        "17928899.62484339" # Can be ignored
    ]
]
```

I would like to do two things. One one hand, plot the candlesticks. On the other hand, extract the "volume" and "Close time" on a separate data structure for further analysis.

How can I do it? I am strglugling with Matplot lib and data structures. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for better handling, you can extract only the 5 values you need.
Let `D` be the overall data structure, the you can extract "Open", "Close", "High", "Low", "Close Time", "Volume" as follows:

```
Open = map(lambda record: record[1], D)
Close = map(lambda record: record[4], D)
High = map(lambda record: record[2], D)
Low = map(lambda record: record[3], D)
CloseTime = map(lambda record: record[6], D)
Volume = map(lambda record: record[5], D)
```

by, of course, assuming that "Open" is always the 2nd item, "Close" is always the 5th item and so on. Recall that Python uses 0-based indexing, so the 2nd item has index 1, the 5th item has index 4, the 1st item has index 0 and so on.

However, "Open", "High", "Low", "Close" and "Volume" are strings and I reckon you want them as float (i.e. numerical) for plotting purposes. If that's the case

```
Open = [float(item) for item in Open]
Close = [float(item) for item in Close]
High = [float(item) for item in High]
Low = [float(item) for item in Low]
Volume = [float(item) for item in Volume]
```

As far as I can tell, "Close Time" already is numerical, so no casting is required.

This basically answers the second part of your post, namely "how can I extract things from such data structure". As far as the plotting is concerned, according to the [matplotlib candlestick help page](https://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html#matplotlib.finance.candlestick_ochl) you need to create a list of tuple where each tuple contains a sequence of (time, open, close, high, low). Therefore

```
quotes = [(CloseTime[i], Open[i], Close[i], High[i], Low[i]) for i in range(len(Close))]
```

and then you can plot the candlesticks.

Note: without a minimal example or a more complete subset of data is quite hard to fully replicate your problem.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful! I then created a top row (etiq), put evething in columns with Pandas (q2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(quotes, columns=etiq)) and then could plot it!